# How to Find cardinality of $|\{f|f:A \to P(A) \}|$ if $|A|=a$ (A infinite set)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let A infinite set

$|A|=a$

$B=\{x|x \in P(A)\}$

$C=\{f|f:A \to P(A)\}$

$F=\{$ Set of all the relations on $A \times B \}$

$H=\{g|g:B \to B \}$

1) Find $|C|$

2)Find $|F\times H|$

for (1) i think $|P(A)^A|= |P(A)|^{|A|}=2^a$
is that correct and how to find (2)

thanks

Comment: "All relations from A to B"? You mean relations on $A\times B$ or functions from $A$ to $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $|C|=|F|$.

The number of function from one element of $B$ to all the elements of $B$ is $2^{a}$. It means that $|H|=(2^{a})^{2^{a}}$.

These are the solutions:
$$|C|=2^{a}*a$$
$$|H \times F|= (2^{a})^{2^{a}}*|F|= (2^{a})^{2^{a}+1}*a$$

These solutions consider all types of function.

Comment: the first one i understand it  $|C|=|F|=$$|A \times B|$ $= |A| * |B| = a * |P(A)| =$ $a*2^a$ . can you explain the second one  please

Comment: I modified my answer.